# How to get the FragmentManager by the views ID?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I get the `FragmentManager` of a View?

Assuming I have a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
<fragment android:name="com.example.MyFragment"
        android:id="@+id/thefragmentsid" >
</fragment>
...
```

Here is my pseudo code (I know that not even `FragmentView` exists, but I guess you know what I mean)

```java
FragmentView fw = (FragmentView) activity.findViewById( R.id.thefragmentsid );
FragmentManager goal = fw.getFragment().getFragmentManager();
```

And here is an example use case:

```java
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.my_fragments_view, container, false );
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findViewById( R.id.thefragmentsid ).setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event ){
                FragmentView fw = (FragmentView) findViewById( R.id.thefragmentsid );
                FragmentManager fm = fw.getFragment().getFragmentManager();
                // Do something with the fragment manager
                return false;
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I do not have access to any `Fragment`-Object in any way I know. Maybe there is a hidden way but exactly for that I'm asking!

**NEXT EDIT:** (Just to complete the question afterwards) I'm using the Google Support Package!

PS: I don't want to give too much involved infos because it's a general question which requires a general answer and could appear occasionally.

Comment: Not only did the link I posted 100% answer your question, but I posted an example. What else do you want?

Comment: @willmel 1) Sure, I am an android developer and have never seen that link you are talking about - alias _the android developing site_. Dream on^^ No, I wasn't able to find an answer in the android guide. 2) I'm really sorry but I can't see where in your answer you're answering. This sounds much more nasty than it's meant to be, I'm just wondering if you read my question carefully (I've done some edits). If you are really sure your answer is correct, please could you try to constellate it in a way I can understand?

Comment: Maybe I really did not understand some important things about Fragments but in this case please try to teach them to me, I am willing to learn!

Comment: Please, read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Comment: One of only a few well-written pieces of android documentation. It will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: @willmel Haven't you read, I read this? o.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it is really my own mistake, I see. I thought it had to be a function called `getFragmentManager()` but exactly that was the mistake.

The correct function is called `getSupportFragmentManager()` since I use Googles Support Package.

But one has to say there is a big trap because inside of a `Fragment` even with the Support Package one can use the `Fragment`s function `getFragmentManager()` but inside of an `FragmentActivity` it's suddenly `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

I admit it's great disgrace, especially that I thought it wouldn't be a necessary information, that I use the Support Package. I thought it would keep the question more general but I see I never should retain any information. For future questions :)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Create your fragments in code, and assign them a view in the same way you'd assign an Activity a view. To add the fragment into XML, use the fragment you created in code.

ie.

```
 <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
            android:id="@+id/viewer"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

then in your code behind, give it a view

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Now that you have your fragment in code, you can use :

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager();
```

`getActivity` is the shorthand to get the `Activity` the `Fragment` belongs to. It's possible a `Fragment` is not attached to an `Activity`.

Because of this, wait until onActivityCreated or see if getActivity is null.

Comment: And "getActivity" is a method of which class/object?

Comment: @MatteoBonaker is a function in Fragment.

Comment: But I am not in any fragments context, where shall I get this?

Comment: @Matmarbon please update your original post with the use case. Are you trying to access from the XML layout?